# FAR Maven 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: far-manager, maven

I have working installation of Maven. If I use 'mvn whatever' commands in FAR it works. If, however, I try to use the view feature - 'view: < mvn whatever', I get the 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command error. Any ideas why that could happen?

Comment: Works on my end... What is `mvn` on your system? In my case it's a batch file in the `%PATH%`, which `CALL`s the actual maven `mvn.bat` in Maven's `bin` folder...

Comment: I am assuming(?) 'mvn' == '%MAVEN_HOME%/bin/mvn.bat'. Im actually not sure how all the Maven black magic works. Are you suggesting creating another .bat file that calls mvn.bat?

Comment: Not really - to be honest, I didn't even know of that `view:<[COMMAND]` technique. Nevertheless it works even with two chained batch files on my end and I can also do `view:<%MAVEN_HOME%\bin\mvn.bat` just fine. It's really strange you can execute `mvn` in FAR just fine, but not in this "view output" mode.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in Far Manager.
You should try [recent](http://www.farmanager.com/download.php) versions (there are a were fixes in `view:` command)